# Are the Canadian Journey Series banknotes still accepted in shops in Canada?

Tags: canada

I assume they are accepted in banks however,  having seen the big hassle tourists go through in the UK when they have an old banknote I would love to know if I can spend them in shops.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since [the Bank of Canada page on the series](https://www.bankofcanada.ca/banknotes/bank-note-series/canadian-journey/) includes instructions on how to check these notes, I believe the answer is **yes.**

I do note that the page also instructs merchants "But if you have doubts when verifying any note, ask for another one." So it's possible a small store could ask for a different bill. This is completely different from the "you can't use that here, take it to a bank; oh ha ha we meant a bank you have an account with; why would a bank exchange notes for strangers you need to go to a currency exchange place and accept their outrageous fee" situation I faced with old banknotes in the UK.

Comment: Anti-money laundering risk is the reason why banks don’t accept notes from customers who do not have an account with them.

Comment: Even my own branch won't change notes for new issue ones. Due to "money-laundering regulations" it has to be paid into my account (then I can withdraw it).

Comment: *ask for another one* -- What if the customer does not have other notes (or does not want to produce them)? Is the shopkeeper forced by law to accept that note, or not?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni as far as I know “forced” is a myth in this situation regardless of the country

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Shops don't have to serve you at all.  They can decide to close for a week in the middle of the day and not sell anyone anything if they like.  Legal tender laws apply only to debts.  If you're already in debt to someone then they are required to accept legal tender as payment.  If you're just negotiating a sale, either party can decline to commit to the transaction for almost any reason.

Comment: @J... Suppose I am at a restaurant, and after eating my dinner I ask for the check and try to pay with an old 50. What happens?

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/31224/can-someone-deny-cash-as-the-payment-method/31280#31280

Answer (score 6):

The tourist is much less likely to encounter "old notes" in Canada than in the UK, though it is conceivable that it might happen.  This is due to differing policies and histories of the respective national banks.

The issues that arise with old banknotes not being accepted in shops/stores in the UK is, I believe, because they are no longer legal tender.  The Bank of England has in recent years [withdrawn several relatively new banknotes,](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/banknotes/withdrawn-banknotes) including commonly-used £5 and £10 notes that were being issued as recently as 2016 but which stopped being legal tender in 2017 and 2018 respectively.  The [Royal Mint has estimated](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-wales-57990329) that there are still about £1.3 billion worth of old £5 and £10 notes in circulation five years later.  Note also that paper £20 and £50 notes will be withdrawn in September 2022, so this problem may well persist for a while.

In contrast, the Bank of Canada has not been as aggressive in declaring old banknotes to no longer be legal tender.  The Bank of Canada did not have the power to do so until 2018, and so far the only notes that the Bank of Canada has removed this status from are the [$1, $2, $25, $500, and $1000 notes](https://www.bankofcanada.ca/banknotes/about-legal-tender/), regardless of age.  The BoC stopped issuing the $1000 note in 2000 (and most tourists would never have encountered one anyway), the $2 in 1996, and the $1 in 1989.  (The other two denominations haven't been issued in decades.) There are only about [$350 million in $1 and $2 notes](https://www.bankofcanada.ca/rates/banking-and-financial-statistics/bank-of-canada-note-liabilities-formerly-k1/) still in circulation today, making these "old notes" much less of a problem for a tourist.  And as of November 2021,

> The [Canadian] government currently has no plans to take any bank notes other than the $1, $2, $25, $500 and $1,000 notes out of circulation. It will be able to remove other notes in the future as needed.

Of course, it is conceivable that if you used a really old banknote in Canada (for example, a note from the "Birds of Canada" series, which stopped being printed in the early '00s) that a shopkeeper might be leery of it.  But there is no widespread policy about such notes no longer being acceptable like there is in the UK.

Comment: Also, I miss the ["Birds of Canada" series.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birds_of_Canada_(banknotes))

Comment: I didn't encounter old banknotes in the uk; I brought my old banknotes home after a trip and several years later returned to discover "those aren't money any more." Also those "in circulation" numbers include a LOT in people's bedrooms (we have some framed $2's) and otherwise not going to be spent.

Comment: I'd note that cash in general is on its deathbed, with even illegal transactions moving to things like Bitcoin over time. The vast majority of tourists in Canada would not touch cash in general.

Comment: When I asked in my bank about the September 2022 deadline for paper £50 and £20 notes they said they would continue to accept them for some time after: but I needn't worry, the Bank of England will still accept them, because their notes declare "I promise to pay the bearer on demand the sum of £xx" signed by the Chief Cashier. The problem there, though, is that the Bank of England does not have any branches with public access.

Comment: @WeatherVane:  According to [this page](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/banknotes/exchanging-old-banknotes)  "The Bank of England Counter at Threadneedle Street, London, EC2R 8AH is currently open from 9.30am to 3pm Monday to Friday."  There's a long list of rigamarole you have to go through, but it appears that you can exchange old banknotes there (and of course you have to get to the city, which may be a nuisance.)  Also, you can apparently exchange old banknotes with the BoE by post, if you're willing to trust in the rectitude of the employees of the Royal Mail.

Comment: Thanks, I can't now find the reference to my misinformation. I had googled it earlier today (not told that by my bank).

Comment: It was very common for UK nightclubs and bars to prominently post "NO WHITE 50 POUND NOTES ACCEPTED HERE.  Too easy to photocopy.